# Redirect subdomain to the same subdomain + folder in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to redirect in AWS my subdomain to that same subdomain but with folder name included. For example, I created a subdomain prev.subdomain.com in AWS and its A record is pointed to the public IP of CrazyDomain hosting (this is where the website is hosted). What I wanted to do is create a redirection in AWS wherein if I type prev.subdomain.com in URL it will redirect to prev.subdomain.com/folder.

FYI. The DNS management of subdomain.com is in AWS.

Comment: this can't be done in DNS, you'll need to use some sort of proxy or redirection service

Answer (score 1):

it cannot be done on dns layer.. but can be easily done using .htaccess or configuration file of your web server like apache or nginx